# Python 3.3 Multithreading argument sequence

Tags: python, multithreading, arguments, sequence

I have been making a small piece of code to test threading while a FOR loop is running, and also running different functions in a different class.

The code works very well, except that if you want it to thread more than 10 seconds, IDLE gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 594, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: main() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

It seems to be a problem with the threading.py module, but there surely must be a solution.

Below here is the code I have:

```
import threading, time

class Application:
    def __init__(self):       
        self.main()

    def main(self)        
        global count
        count = int(input("How many seconds do you want it to Thread?\n"))
        if count:
            thread = Threading(count)
        else:
            pass

    def test(self):
        print("Printing in another class.", self)


class Threading:
    def __init__(self, y):
        print("Starting Thread...")
        number = str(count)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main, args=number)
        thread.start()
        for i in range(count):          
            print("Looping...", i)
            time.sleep(1)

    def main(self, argument):
        while (int(argument)>0):
            print("Threading...", argument)
            argument = int(argument) - 1
            Application.test(argument)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
```

*If i change the `str` and `int` pieces around in the code, the thread won't run at all, because the agument has to be a sequence.*
So my question is, how do I make the code able to run more than 10 "seconds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself! 
The argument needed to be a tuple, so I changed the original multithreading line to the following:

```
 thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main, args=(number,))
```

before it was just `args=number`